# Android PDF font is not readable

Tags: android, react-native, pdf, android-webview

I'm using `react-native-html-to-pdf` to convert HTML to PDF and `react-native-pdf` to view PDF.

For past few days, some of the Android users reported that the generated PDF is not readable. This image below is one the examples:

[image]

To debug this issue, we bought a new android 12 phone. First day the PDF was readable in that phone without any issue. After a while, the PDF became unreadable on the new phone also.

On the other side, there are some android phones are facing this issue "partially". In some android phones if we set the html `font-weight:bold` the PDF is showing perfectly. But unfortunately it's not working in all the phones.

Phones where font-weight:bold is working:

1. Redmi
2. Samsung

Phones where we could not find any solution:

1. Vivo
2. Oppo

I'm guessing it's happening maybe because of some Android update. After some digging we found out that both `react-native-html-to-pdf` and `react-native-pdf` is using WebView for generating and viewing pdf respectively. Could it be because of some Android WebView update causing this issue? I planned create an issue in those library repositories but I think both of them are not actively maintained.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After some more digging we found out that this happens due to converting HTML to PDF.

Code for Generating PDF:

```
// @author: https://github.com/mddanishansari/
        var pdfGenerationStarted = false
        try {
            val pdfWebView = WebView(context)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                pdfWebView.settings.safeBrowsingEnabled = false
            }
            val attributes = getPrintAttributes()
            val printAdapter = getPrintAdapter(pdfWebView, Math.random().toString())

            pdfWebView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)

                    if (pdfWebView.progress == 100 && !pdfGenerationStarted) {

                        pdfGenerationStarted = true

                        val pdfPrinter = PdfPrinter(attributes)
                        pdfPrinter.generate(printAdapter, pdfLocation, onPdfGenerated)
                        Log.i("PDFConverter","HTML has been loaded");
                    }
                }
            }

            pdfWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl, htmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null)
```

Print Adapter

```
printAdapter.onLayout(null, printAttributes, null, object : LayoutResultCallback() {
                override fun onLayoutFinished(info: PrintDocumentInfo, changed: Boolean) {
                    printAdapter.onWrite(
                        arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES),
                        getOutputFile(path),
                        CancellationSignal(),
                        object : WriteResultCallback() {
                            override fun onWriteFinished(pages: Array<PageRange>) {
                                super.onWriteFinished(pages)
                                onPdfGenerated(path)
                            }
                        })
                }
            }, null)
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same issue. This issue is because of Android System Webview version. The version which is currently in stable has issues when converting HTML to PDF.

The fix is available in version : 103.0.5060.70

Please update the system webview version and check.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented that for both iOS and Android successfully.

Here's how

Libs: react-native-html-to-pdf, react-native-print (please use that library instead for printing, much easier)

Imports

```
import RNHTMLtoPDF from 'react-native-html-to-pdf';
import RNPrint from 'react-native-print';
```

Options (You can even embed styling)

```
let options = {
    html: '...', //plain html like <div style="width: 100%; display: inline-flex; margin-top: -20px; margin-bottom: 20px;"><div style="flex: 1; margin: 5px;"><h5>FİRMA: ' + printedEnterpriseName + '</h5></div></div></div>
    fileName: 'test'
};
```

Print

```
let file = await RNHTMLtoPDF.convert(options)
await RNPrint.print({filePath: file.filePath});
```

Further reading

https://reactnativeexample.com/print-documents-using-react-native/

https://aboutreact.com/react-native-print-html/

Comment: Hi, I don't have issue in printing. When I generate the PDF and view in the app, it shows weird font encoding. It happens only in viewing.

Comment: Try my approach, we've never had any issues like that

Comment: "react-native-pdf is using WebView for generating and viewing pdf respectively." Using my approach, you will use native printing feature on the screen.

Comment: Ok in my case it's not workable cause I allow user to sign the statement, put rating and so on. Moving native feature won't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution for this right now. @Saikrishna confirmed also. However, I found an alternative.

I have shared the solution [here](https://github.com/wonday/react-native-pdf/issues/658#issuecomment-1171210443)